# Cannot set permissions to 600 on SSH key file

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to delete all permissions on my private key file in order to make only me the owner have access to it but it brought this error

```
chmod: prac1: new permissions are ----w--w-, not ---------
```

Please how can i solve this error because without solving this error i can't make my private key file private and i can't login into my server. Someone please help thank you

Here are the commands I used
It has been solved thank you
it was solved here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317541/why-is-chmod-rwx-not-removing-all-the-permissions-on-my-private-key-file-the-a
Thank you so much!

```
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod -rwx prac1*
chmod: prac1.pub: new permissions are ----w--w-, not ---------

abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1*

abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod u+r,go-rwx prac1

abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*

abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chown abayomi prac1

abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*

abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod 600 prac1

abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*
```

Comment: What was your command?

Comment: try `chmod u+r,go-rwx prac1`, usefull information might also be found using `man chmod` or if `man`is not in WSL, go to  internet => 'man page for chmod`

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: @Abayomi tell us the exact command you used, by editing the question.

Comment: It looks like your file names have literal astrixes in them.  use `chmod 600 prac1\* praac1.pub\*`. Since this seems like a mistake, you could aos rename the files to versions without astrixes `mv prac1\* prac1` and `mv prac1.pub\* prac1.pub` and then run `chmod 600 prac1 prac1.pub`

Comment: I don't understand why you need `grep` and wonder what `ll` (which is not a command but most likely an alias) does. Can you show `ls -l prac1*` instead? And run `chmod` with the `-v` option for verbose output.

Comment: Voting to close since it was crossposted and answered elsewhere (and is really a question about the Windows `drvfs` filesystem)

Comment: Agreed.  @Abayomi - It is considered bad form to post the same question on multiple Stack sites at the same time.  It wastes the time of the people looking at it by dividing the efforts.  Also, you provided more information on the AskUbuntu that made the answer obvious (to me at least) that you didn't provide here.

Answer (score 2):

Files only have one owner.  You can set the owner with `chown <user> <file>`.

If your file looked like this, here are the permissions

```
-rw-r--r--  abayomi   abayomi   private.key
 || || ||     |           |            |
 || || ||     |           |             +---- filename
 || || ||     |           +------------------ owning group
 || || ||     +------------------------------ owning user
 || || |+------------------------------------ others cannot write
 || || +------------------------------------- others can read
 || |+--------------------------------------- owning group cannot write
 || +---------------------------------------- owning group can read
 |+------------------------------------------ owning user can write
 +------------------------------------------- owning user can read
```

I think you want `chmod 600 private.key`  this will give you:

```
-rw-------  abayomi   abayomi   private.key
 || || ||     |           |            |
 || || ||     |           |             +---- filename
 || || ||     |           +------------------ owning group
 || || ||     +------------------------------ owning user
 || || |+------------------------------------ others cannot write
 || || +------------------------------------- others cannot read
 || |+--------------------------------------- owning group cannot write
 || +---------------------------------------- owning group cannot read
 |+------------------------------------------ owning user can write
 +------------------------------------------- owning user can read
```

`600` is a three digit octal number where:

```
600             6 = 110
|||                 |||
||+--- other        ||+--- execute permission
|+---- group        |+---- write permission
+----- user         +----- read permission
```

Comment: This is what happened after applying your solution, it didn't delete the permissions as it was supposed to  chown abayomi prac1
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod 600 prac1
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*

Comment: @Steward : albeit right, the description you give about the octal mode digits may be misleading : the 3 digits are respectively for "user", "group" and "others". "anyone" sounds like a valid synonymous for "others", but in symbolic mode, chmod accepts directives like "a+r", granting read access to "all" : "user" AND "group" AND "others". Saying the 3rd digit is for "anyone" could mislead about what this "a" means in symbolic mode. Details : https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html

Comment: @Httqm updated.